# How can I perform actions on a mail created with redirect?

Tags: redirect, applescript

I have written - with the help of various sources of course -, this script to redirect mail in bulk: it redirects all mail selected in the mail app. There seems to be nothing special going on.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    set theRedirectRecipient to "redirectmail@mail.mail"
    set theRedirectSender to "Sender"
    set theMessages to the selection

    repeat with thisMessage in theMessages
        tell application "Mail"
            set theRedirectedEmail to redirect thisMessage with opening window
            tell theRedirectedEmail
                if subject of thisMessage is "" then
                    set subject of theRedirectedEmail to "Mails zonder subject"
                end if

                make new to recipient at beginning of to recipients with properties {address:theRedirectRecipient}
                #delete bcc recipients
                #delete cc recipients
            end tell
            #delay 2
            #send theRedirectedEmail
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

As above, the script runs fine: it creates the redirect mail, and if I press the send button, it works like I need it to.

But there are 3 lines commented out that do not work. The delete lines and the send line. I'm not really sure I care about the delete ones, but I have included them in case someone can see a pattern.

Uncommenting one of those lines gives me this error:

> error "Mail got an error: Can’t get every cc recipient of outgoing
>   message id 18." number -1728 from every cc recipient of outgoing
>   message id 18

Again, this does create a message-window that I can send successfully if done by hand.

Uncommenting the 'send' line introduces the following error:

> error "Mail got an error: outgoing message id 19 doesn’t understand
>   the “send” message." number -1708 from outgoing message id 19

So what I have concluded is that the created message doesn't behave as a message 'should'. I have seen [this thread](http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-users/2010/Jan/msg00387.html) about an 'outgoing message' that seems to display this behaviour.

What is going on with this message called `theRedirectEmail`? How can I send messages to this object, like `delete` and `send`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this same issue. Here's the workaround I came up with. In some ways, it's actually easier:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    set theRedirectRecipient to "redirectmail@mail.mail"
    set theRedirectSender to "Sender"
    set theMessages to the selection

    repeat with thisMessage in theMessages
        redirect thisMessage with opening window
        tell application "System Events"
            tell application process "Mail"
                tell window 1

                    --wait for mail message to appear before continuing

                    repeat while not (text field "To:" exists)
                    end repeat

                    set value of text field "To:" to theRedirectRecipient
                    set value of text field "Cc:" to ""
                    if text field "Bcc:" exists then
                        set value of text field "Bcc:" to ""
                    end if
                    if value of text field "Subject:" is equal to "" then
                        set value of text field "Subject:" to "Mails zonder subject"
                    end if
                end tell
                tell application "Mail" to activate
                click menu item "Send" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Message" of menu bar 1
            end tell
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

You have to tell Mail to activate, because Mail doesn't allow the sending of email when it's in the background, probably to prevent evil-doers from spamming your entire contacts list in the background, without your knowledge, using AppleScript. This may be related to the strange behavior of mail regarding outgoing messages too, though I can't be sure...

Comment: Ok, I think I get it, but I'm not getting it to work with the repeat I'm using; you are using a 2-step method basically, with 2 `tell` blocks, but as i'm in that loop, I'm not sure enough of applescript to know what to do. Any tips on how to merge your example with my code?

Comment: Sorry, I was being lazy. I updated it with a merged version. It should do the trick.

Comment: thanks! I'm not very known with applescript as you might have gathered, this really helps me :D

Comment: Ideally, I would remove the Systen Events block from the tell Mail statement and place it in its own handler.

Comment: @adayzdone that doesn't really make sense in this instance. The code could easily be refactored in such a way if needed, but the script doesn't currently need it. Always good to keep in mind though!

Comment: Best practice is to avoid nested tell statements.

Comment: @adayzdone That can't be correct. There are times, as clearly exemplified in my code, where you MUST nest tells. You tell system events to tell an application process to tell a window, etc. Refactoring, in this case, means more jumping around your source file to track the script's logic. That's a tiny amount mental overhead for no benefit, in this case. The code I wrote is the best practice, in this instance. If I was worried about using the code again in the future, I would create a separate handler for it, but that isn't likely to be the case here. GUI scripting is almost never reusable.

Comment: Telling system events to tell an application process is an instance where there must be a nested tell. Tell application "Mail" to tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Mail" is not. Ultimately it is not wrong, but for the sake of readability, I would put it in its own handler.